# How to capture the value in redux-form every time when different option from select was chosen?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am new to react and redux-form. I have a form that rendered select field options with data I get from an API. It query new API with key value from the select field whenever I choose an option. Then I want the other two fields to display and set their value base on the new API query which happen every time I choose new option. Placing the value on the field's placeholder only display the value but it will not capture the value when submit. I test this by using values from redux-form-website-template. It only show the key and value from the select field but not other fields. What should I do in order to capture the value every time I change the select field option? Will formalize or format do the job? I tried value={this.value} and not working.

```
//All relevant imports 

class MyFormClass extends Components {
   componentDidMount() {
        //first query
        this.props.dispatch(getFoodAction())
   }

   onChange = (event) => {
        //second API query with the key value from select
        this.props.dispatch(getFoodByIDAction(event.target.value))
   }

   render() {
        const { handleSubmit, fruit } = this.props
        let food_list = this.props.food.map((food, index) => {
            return (
                <option value={ food.id } >
                    { food.name }   
                </option>
            )
        })

        return(
            <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.submit) } >
                <div>
                   <Field 
                        value={this.value}
                        name="food" 
                        component="select"
                        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} >
                        {food_list}
                    </Field>
                    <div>
                        <label><b>Food Category</b> : </label>
                        <Field 
                            name="food_category"
                            component="input"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder={ food.category}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label><b>Food Detail</b> : </label>
                        <Field 
                            name="food_detail"
                            component="textarea"
                            type="text"
                            placeholder={ food.detail}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

const reduxFormFood = reduxForm({
    form: 'foodForm'
})(MyFormClass)

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        food: state.foodreducer.food,
        foodbyid: state.foodbyidreducer.food
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    { getFoodAction, getFoodByIDAction }
)(reduxFormFood );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I rewrite the whole component, new reducer and new action by referencing [the redux-form initializefromstate example](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/)